# The name `Math' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, floating-point, unity-game-engine, rounding

I have the Code below and I'm trying to round the PerlinNoise(x,z) so I've put it equal to Yscale and tried to round it. the issue is that I get the error "The name `Math' does not exist in the current context" for that Line. Any Ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class voxelcreate : MonoBehaviour {
private int origin = 0;
private Vector3 ChunkSize = new Vector3 (32,6,32);
private float Height = 10.0f;
private float NoiseSize = 10.0f;
private float Yscale=0;
private GameObject root;
public float PerlinNoise(float x, float y)
{
    float noise = Mathf.PerlinNoise( x / NoiseSize, y / NoiseSize );
    return noise * Height;

}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    for(int x = 0; x < 33; x++){
        bool isMultiple = x % ChunkSize.x == 0;
        if(isMultiple == true){
        origin = x;
Chunk();}
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame

void Chunk (){
    int ranNumber = Random.Range(8, 80);
    int ranNumber2 = Random.Range(8, 20);
    Height = ranNumber2;
    NoiseSize = ranNumber;
    for(int x = 0; x < ChunkSize.x; x++)
    {
for(int y = 0; y < ChunkSize.y; y++)
{
    for(int z = 0; z < ChunkSize.z; z++)
    {
GameObject box = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                int Yscale = (int)Math.Round((PerlinNoise( x, z)), 0);
           box.transform.position = new Vector3( origin+x , y+Yscale, z);
}}}}}
```

Comment: You should really use an IDE.  It solves these problems for you automatically.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add

```
using System;
```

at the top of the file.

Or use `System.Math` instead of `Math`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: *using System.Math* - doesn't work. Only *using System*.

Comment: This answer doesn't propose using `using System.Math`. It proposes that they add the `using` statement or use `System.Math` each time to refer to `Math` if they choose not to use `using`.

Answer (score 2):

It is true you could add `using System`. However, Unity has [Mathf](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.html)

**Why would you rather use the built in Mathf?**

`System.Math` uses doubles. `UnityEngine.Mathf` uses floats. Since most of Unity uses floats, it is better to use `Mathf` so that you don't have to constantly convert floats and doubles back and forth.

Comment: He's already converting the value to `int`, so if that is done from a `float` or a `double` doesn't make any difference. It feels like you are trying to answer something that isn't in the question.

Comment: He might be converting to an `int` now. However, for future reference `Mathf` is useful to be aware of. Your comment implies that knowing how a system works, as long as you can patch together your code, is not important -- I don't subscribe to that point of view.

Comment: I'm not implying any such thing. Please don't put words in my mouth, that is not very polite.

Comment: I still see the benefit, for the OP, to be informed about a specialized `Mathf` which is built into the engine he is already using.

Answer (score 2):

**In ASP.NET Core, you need to get the System.Runtime.Extension package first**, maybe via NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio or by command line.

Details about the package can be found [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Extensions/4.1.0).

Finally you need to give:

```
using System
```

And then you can use methods of this class:

```
            using System;
            namespace Demo.Helpers
            {
                public class MathDemo
                {
                    public int GetAbsoluteValue()
                    {
                        var negativeValue = -123;
                        return Math.Abs(negativeValue);
                    }
                }
            }
```